# Using Docker compose and volumes to persist uploaded pictures directory

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm working on an ecommerce, I want to have the ability to upload product photos from the client and save them in a directory on the serve.

I implemented this feature but then I understood that since we use docker for our deployment, the directory in which I save the pictures won't persist. as I searched, I kinda realized that I should use volumes and map that directory in docker compose. I'm a complete novice backend developer (I work on frontend) so I'm not really sure what I should do.

Here is the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nodejs:
    image: node:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=[REDACTED]
      - FRONT_SITE_ADDRESS=[REDACTED]
      - SITE_ADDRESS=[REDACTED]
    container_name: [REDACTED]
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    ports:
      - "8888:7070"
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    command: node dist/main.js
    links:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[REDACTED]
    container_name: product-mysql
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    volumes:
      - ../data:/var/lib/mysql
```

If I want to store the my photos in `../static/images` (ralative to the root of my project), what should I do and how should refer to this path in my backend code?

Backend is in nodejs (Nestjs).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `volume` and tell to docker-compose/docker stack mount it within the container specify the path you wamth. See the `volumes` to the very end of the file and the `volumes` option on `nodejs` service.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nodejs:
    image: node:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=[REDACTED]
      - FRONT_SITE_ADDRESS=[REDACTED]
      - SITE_ADDRESS=[REDACTED]
    container_name: [REDACTED]
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    ports:
      - "8888:7070"
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
      - static-files:/home/node/static/images
    command: node dist/main.js
    links:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[REDACTED]
    container_name: product-mysql
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    volumes:
      - ../data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
 static-files:{}
```

Doing this an empty container will be crated persisting your data and every time a new container mounts this path you can get the data stored on it. I would suggest to use the same approach with `mysql` instead of saving data within the host.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference